# How can I post a marker onto Google Maps from a separate fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to post a marker onto a map from a separate fragment. So when you tap a button, the fragment manager will take you to the map fragment and then show you your newly placed marker. But I'm having some (nullPointer) issues.

I'm getting a null pointer because I'm trying to add a marker before the map loads. I've tried some methods to find a way to add the marker when the map is ready but I couldn't get anything to work.

Is there a clean solution to adding a marker when the map is ready?

Also, here's the error that comes up:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference

**EDIT:** The way I'm getting the marker information (LatLng) is with a method I found on stackoverflow. What it does is, it takes the address from an EditText and retrieves the Latitude and Longitude points from it. I use that to store it into 'marker' and 'point'. The method is found below...

**UPDATE:** It no longer gives me a null exception. The MapFragment loads but there's no marker to be seen.

In my PostFragment class:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setUpSpinners();
    Button button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.postButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText editEvent = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.map_location);
                    point = getLocationFromAddress(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), editEvent.getText().toString());

                    marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("New Marker");

                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frag, new GoogleMapFragment()).commit();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void addThisMarker(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.addMarker(marker
            .position(point)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
}
```

And in my MapFragment class:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    globalMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap(); //just enabling some map properties here
    PostFragment x = new PostFragment();

    x.addThisMarker(globalMap);

}
```

**And this is the method I'm using, in PostFragment, to retrieve LatLng from an address

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return p1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        MapFragment fMap = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fmap.getMapAsync(this);
    }

     @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        // Draw your marker here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting the null pointer exception. I made a method that adds a marker in my post fragment (the fragment with just the button) and the method has a GoogleMap parameter. 

And I put that method right under where I set map = googleMap; (with 'map' in the parameter). Still giving me the same exception.

Comment: Yeah sure, is it alright if I post it in a paste bin and link it here or is against the rules?

Comment: It's better if you post the relevant parts here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should edit your question and add the details there not on the comments. If you keep improving your question and updating it, your question will gain visibility, it will receive more visitors and hence more possible answers

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry. I'm still new to this. One sec.

Comment: Okay, I'm finished. Every single thing you need to know is there.

Comment: I think your `point` variable is `null` when you call `addThisMarker`

Comment: Yeah, I actually just noticed this! I'm just going to try and handle that null value, so call addThisMarker when point isn't null

Comment: It's working now. I just added some handlers and we're good. :) Thanks!!!